# Test returns "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" on func that throws

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctestcase

I am writing a network layer, following a TDD approach.

I have a struct that I will be using to encode any parameters in my request.

I would like to assert that should a URL be missing / nil when invoking this encoder, the correct error is thrown.

```
struct URLParameterEncoder: ParameterEncoder {
    static func encode(urlRequest: inout URLRequest, with parameters: Parameters) throws {
        guard let url = urlRequest.url else { throw NetworkError.missingURL }
    }
}
```

I have written a test and passed in a URL which I believe should satisfy this test, however am getting an error when trying to run the test.

```
class URLParameterEncoderTests: XCTestCase {
    var sut: URLParameterEncoder!

    override func setUp() {
        sut = URLParameterEncoder()
    }

    func test_Encode_ThrowsMissingURLError_WhenURLIsNil() {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "")!)
        let params: Parameters = [:]

        XCTAssertThrowsError(try sut.encode(urlRequest: &request, with: params)) { error in
            XCTAssertEqual(error as? NetworkError, NetworkError.missingURL)
        }
    }
}
```

In my `XCTAssertThrowsError` I am getting `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` which I believe is being triggered around `sut.encode`

Additional code required to replicate

```
public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]

public protocol ParameterEncoder {
    static func encode(urlRequest: inout URLRequest, with parameters: Parameters) throws
}

public enum NetworkError: String, Error {
    case paramsAreNil = "Missing params"
    case encodingFailed = "Could not encode params"
    case missingURL = "Request URL is missing"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding *more context* – a question mark for optional chaining because `sut` is still an optional –

```
XCTAssertThrowsError(try sut?.encode(urlRequest: &request, with: params)) { error in ...
```

you get the real error

> Static member 'encode' cannot be used on instance of type 'URLParameterEncoder'

It means that `encode` must be called on the type `URLParameterEncoder.encode(...`

---

However this raises a new error

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'request' is a 'let' constant

That means an `inout` parameter like `request` must be declared as variable: `var request = ...`